# Get contents of multipage datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am trying to read the contents of a jQuery datatable. I was able to loop through the rows, but I don't know how to get the content.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
table.rows().every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
    var d = this.data();
    var item = {
        id: // Get first column content
        description: //Get second column content
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried with `id: d[0]` and so on ..? If you have a table based on JSON it would be `id: d.id`  (if `id` is a property of `data()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can use:

```
table.rows().every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
    var nodes = this.nodes().to$();
    var item = {
       id: nodes.find('td:eq(0)').text(), // Get first column content
       description: nodes.find('td:eq(1)').text() // Get second column content
    };
});
```

OR

```
table.rows().every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
    var item = {
        id: this.cell(rowIdx,0).data(), // Get first column content
        description: this.cell(rowIdx,1).data() // Get second column content
    };
});
```

You can find more details [here](https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector).

Answer (score 1):

I had used the following code somewhere. Maybe this can work for you.

```
table.rows().iterator('row', function(context, rowIdx){
    var item = { 
        id: $(this.row(rowIdx).node());
        description: $(this.row(rowIdx).node()); 
    }
});
```